# If user presses enter (without anything else) how can I print out the line ("please give a valid command")?

Tags: java, exception

I have a program in java where the user have to give command. However if he presses enter without anything else  the program stops and he gets this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at UserInterface.main(UserInterface.java:43)
```

How is it possible that I can detect with the program that no line is found, and I print out the following ("please give a valid command").

I have tried this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String command = keyboard.nextLine();
if (command == "") {
    System.out.println("please give a valid command");
}
```

Comment: read how to compare strings, this will never work: if(command == ""){

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare two strings in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832380/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use the method `isEmpty()` from the Scanner itself to find out if an input is "nothing".

Try this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = keyboard.nextLine();

if (command.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Please give a valid command.");
    }
```

2) You can't compare two Strings like you did either. If you want to compare them you need to use the `equals(Object anObject)` method.
Here is an example:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = keyboard.nextLine();

if (command.equals("A String"))
    {
        System.out.print("Success");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Surround the statement with try/catch

```
...
String command = "";
try {
  keyboard.nextLine();
} catch (Exceptionn e) {}
...
```

This will catch the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(command.equals("")){
         System.out.println("please give a valid command");
    }
```